# Log topic and subscription message activity on Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-diagnostics

Currently I am working in a solution involving two desktop applications that share messages using Azure Service Bus.

I am trying to isolate an issue where the messages are taking too long to be received by the topic subscriber.

In my test enviroment I am pretty sure the message are alredy sent to the topic, but somehow the subscriber takes too long to receive it.

To receive the messages, I am using a destructive read approach using the service bus REST APIs. The app contantly checks for new messages.

I would like know if I can log when messages arrive at the service bus and when they are destroyed (read), so I can make sure this is not where the problem is located.

I have tried to activate the service bus diagnostics log in the Azure portal, but it seems this is not what I need. Did not see nothing relevant there.

I have also see [an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing), but this uses the client api to receive messages.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like know if I can log when messages arrive at the service bus and when they are destroyed (read), so I can make sure this is not where the problem is located.

Broker side logging as a feature is not available yet. The best you can do is to create a wiretap with a subscription to catch all messages and have a copy of the sent messages stored with that subscription to see when messages were delivered to the broker.

For the seconds part, receiving from the broker by the clients, you'd need to log on the client side.

Comment: I may be missing a service bus concept here: If I create a new subscription to catch all messages, are they gonna be always available for reading (peek) even if the same message was already read (and destroyed) by the subscription used by the client app?

Comment: Yes. Subscriptions under the same topic are independent. Therefore receiving from one subscription is not affecting the other subscription (catch-all subscription).